# What's the meaning of typedef int function(void*)?

Tags: c, function, typedef, bsd

I saw some BSD code using the following construct:

```
typedef int driver_filter_t(void*);
```

What does that mean, exactly? I don't think it's a function pointer because otherwise it would be something like `typedef int (*driver_filter_t)(void*)`, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
typedef int driver_filter_t(void*);
```

This is a definition of a *function type*.  It makes `driver_filter_t` an alias for the type that can be described as "function returning `int` with an argument of type pointer to `void`".

As for all `typedef`s, it creates an alias for an existing type, not a new type.

`driver_filter_t` is *not* a pointer type. You can't declare something of type `driver_filter_t` (the grammar doesn't allow declaring a function using a typedef name). You can declare an object that's a function pointer as, for example:

```
driver_filter_t *func_ptr;
```

Because you can't use a function type name directly without adding a `*` to denote a pointer type, it's probably more common to define `typedef`s for function pointer types, such as:

```
typedef int (*driver_filter_pointer)(void*);
```

But typedefs for function types are pefectly legal, and personally I find them clearer.

Comment: Great answer. I wish K&R had given more attention to this kind of things in their book instead of rushing through the language.

In practical terms, what would be the difference between using a typedef for a function type and a typedef for a function pointer, since you'll be dealing with pointers anyway? Is there anything you can do with the former that you can't do with the latter?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`typedef int driver_filter_t(void*);` is a typedef for a function type. In C you can use it for function pointers like `driver_filter_t* fn_ptr`.

In C++ you can also use that typedef to declare member functions (but not to implement them):

```
struct Some {
    driver_filter_t foo; // int foo(void*);
    driver_filter_t bar; // int bar(void*);
};
```

Comment: Hi Maxim.  Just my opinion, but the OP tagged this question specifically for C.  It's interesting that you can declare member functions for C++ as you show.  However, I think it may cause confusion for someone who is becoming familiar with the C language - particularly since you cannot use that syntax in C.

Comment: @embedded_guy Confused people get clarified the hell out of them here.

Comment: You can also use the typedef in place of a function declaration in C, e.g. `driver_filter_t filterA, filterB, filterC;` in place of `int filterA(void*); int filterB(void*); ...`